# UI freezes while updating ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I know, there are already many threads regarding this topic, but so far I was unable to find a solution for this problem.

First of all, this is my `ItemsControl`:

```
<ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewer}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MaxHeight="475">
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentSelectedItems}"  Margin="0 10 0 0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:ItemControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

To keep it simple, the `ItemsSource` Property of `ItemsControl` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of type `ItemViewModel`.

The `ItemViewModel` contains about 25 Properties and some `Prism DelegateCommands`.

There are also some Buttons on top of the `ItemsControl` to change the content of `CurrentSelectedItems`. Since those items are sometimes up to 300 in total it takes some time to update the UI. While thats the case, the Application is - of cause - frozen.

Is there any way to not freeze the UI and e.G. show a spinner/loading message?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
The `controls:ItemControl` is a simple custom control containing about 5 `Labels` and 3 rather small `Images`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the other answers there is no way to avoid this.

WPF is an SPA (Single Threaded Apartment) meaning any UI objects have to be created and owned by the UI thread.  When you have lots of the UI elements to build and render the UI thread will be busy.

The solution to show a UI loading animation is also incorrect since this animation will also be on the UI thread, the one that is already busy creating and rendering your UI collection.

Just make sure any processing *IS* on a background thread and let the UI manage itself.

Answer (score 0):

Get the WPF Toolkit and use the BusyIndicator.  This will pop up a window on top of your control with a moving busy indicator.  You can provide a custom message with it as well.

Comment: The BusyIndicator will freeze as well, as its on the same GUI-thread...

Answer (score 0):

You can use task to update the UI but it takes a List parameters. To do this:

```
// create an async method
private async void PopulateItems() {
   // use task to populate the items
   await Task.Run(() => {
      for (var item in CurrentSelectedItems) {
          this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => yourItemCollectionControl.Add(item));
      }
   });
}
```